# How to answer to the questions related slots machine using R code?

Tags: r

**Slot machine** with 3 wheels (reels). Each reel has 10 slots, 0, 1, ..., 9. Suppose you have a win if the 3 slots match (0-0-0, 1-1-1, ..., 9-9-9). You decided to play until you win 4  times. What is the probability that you will walk out after at most 350 tries? (round the answer to four decimals)

Comment: You've given us your homework assignment, which isn't specifically a programming question so much as a probability one, but what's the question *you* have? What have you tried and where are you stuck on the code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is self-study, I know that I need to apply negative binominal distribution, but this part *Each reel has 10 slots, 0, 1, ..., 9. Suppose you have a win if the 3 slots match (0-0-0, 1-1-1, ..., 9-9-9)* makes me stuck in writing the code

Comment: For this part of the question, you can use p <- 10/10000

Comment: @Ibrahimli Thank you, I got the code but I am still failing to get the right output

Comment: I think I already explain it in my below answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first of all, we need to know what type of distribution can we apply for this question. We know that, the negative binomial distribution is a discrete probability distribution that models the number of successes in a sequence of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials before a specified (non-random) number of failures (denoted r) occurs. From here,

**pnbinom(q, size, prob, mu, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)**

If we fill the formula with the above inputs, we can get:

```r
r <- 4
p <- 10/10000
pnbinom(346, size = r, prob = p) #it says 4 win, so 350-4
#Or
pnbinom(350-r, size = r, prob = p)

0.00047
```

Comment: This is the same code, except I did not know I need to minus the number of wins from the total.